Find $x_{2017}$ where $x^{2}-\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)^{2}$?
Let $x_{1}<x_{2}< x_{3}<\cdots$ be all real numbers greater than or equal to $1$ satisfying: $x^{2}-\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)^{2}$. Then $x_{2017}$ can be expressed as $\frac{m}{n}$, where $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Find $m+n$
The equation $x^{2}-\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)^{2}$ implies $2x\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor x^2 \rfloor + (\lfloor x \rfloor)^2$, by definition $x=\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$ where $0 \le\{x\}<1$.
Substitute that into the last equation yields and then cancelling terms yields: $\{x^{2}\}=\{x\}^2$
Now I'm not sure where to continue, is there a way I could simplify this?
NOTE: The $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

You say it is nearest integer, then link to the floor function.  Which is it?

Ah, I meant the floor function then.

Write $x=n+y$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in [0,1)$, so that your equation becomes
$$n^2+2ny=\lfloor n^2+2ny+y^2\rfloor.$$
By definition of $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ this is true if and only if $2ny\in \mathbb{Z}$. In other words $x$ has the form
$$n+\frac{m}{2n}$$
for some integers $n\geq 1$ and $0\leq m<2n$. It's now straightforward to examine the behaviour of $x_k$ and find $x_{2017}$. For example note that now you can see there are $2$ elements of the sequence in $[1,2)$ and $4$ in $[2,3)$ etc, so in the interval $[1,m)$ there are $2(1+\cdots+m-1)=m(m-1)$ elements of the sequence.
Since $45(45-1)<2017<46(46-1)$ this means $x_{2017}$ is in the interval $[45,46)$, and now it's easy to find the value of $x_{2017}$.
